# Potential typo in Gathmann's Algebraic geometry example 1.11: why should the generator of this ideal be non-constant?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am reading notes from Gathmann ([https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2021/alggeom-2021-c1.pdf](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/%7Egathmann/class/alggeom-2021/alggeom-2021-c1.pdf)) about algebraic geometry, and in Example $1.11$ he says:

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field and $J\subset K[x]$ be a non-zero ideal. Since $K[x]$ is a principal ideal domain, we have $J = \langle f\rangle$ for a polynomial $f=(x_1-a_1)^{k_1}\cdots(x_1-a_r)^{k_r}$ for some distinct points $a_1,\cdots, a_r\in \mathbb{A}^1$ and $k_1,\cdots,k_r\in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$.

My question is, I think $f$ could not be written as $(x_1-a_1)^{k_1}\cdots(x_1-a_r)^{k_r}$ if $f$ is constant, but here the author only says that $f\neq 0$. Is that $f$ is also not constant in this example?

Comment: Right now this question is very vague: in the title, which notes? A typo about what? In the question, which notes? Which version? Which example? Please improve your question by clearing up some of these ambiguities.

Comment: An empty product is $1$

Comment: @KReiser I have edited. Thank you for reminding!

Comment: @LukasHeger oh is it an implied thing in algebra?

Comment: @Coco yes, indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the example here: Ex 1.11 in [https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2021/alggeom-2021-c1.pdf](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/%7Egathmann/class/alggeom-2021/alggeom-2021-c1.pdf) .
Clearly Gathmann is assuming the ideal is proper.

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense.